# PHP preg_match to get part of my url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to get a part of my url using PHP preg_match but it's not working. I followed some instructions but no luck.

This is what I have so far.

```
$url = 'http://chris.mydomain.com/d/3542re6s/somthing.html';
$pattern = '/\/\/(sub1\.)?mydomain.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/';
preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
if (count($matches)){
  return $matches[2];
}
```

I also need it to validate for chris, terry and jack only.

UPDATED:

eg:
chris.mydomain.com
terry.mydomain.com
jack.mydomain.com

And I need to get the second query

eg:

chris.mydomain.com/d/3542re6s/somthing.html

would return

3542re6s

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
C

Comment: Your regular expression doesn't allow for the `/d/` subdirectory.

Comment: Try parsing the URL first, would be easier to play with it
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: You can allow for sub's 1,2, or 3 with `sub[123]`. Also `\d+` is only numbers, you want the letters as well, no? Is this what you are looking for https://regex101.com/r/iR1fC1/1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is missing the `/d/` directory. Also, since the next level contains both numbers and letters, you can't use `\d+` to match it. Try this:

```
$pattern = '#//(?:(?:chris|terry|jack)\.)?mydomain\.com/d/([^/]+)(?|/)#';
```

[DEMO at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oA1bH8/1)
[PHP demo at ideone](http://ideone.com/4vpX8z)

And when you're writing a regular expression to match pathnames, I suggest using a delimiter other than `/` so you don't have to escape all the slashes in the regexp; I used `#` above.

Comment: So sorry... i wasn't very clear in my example.

Subs are just examples. They wouldn't be any numbers. I've updated my question.

Comment: I've updated the answer to match `chris`, `terry`, or `jack` as the subdomains.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what i'm doing wrong but the $matches aray is empty. Ideas?

Comment: Thanks, I checked it. It shows the whole url as the output but I only need the 2nd query i.e. `3542re6s`

Comment: I had an extra `?:` that was making it a non-capturing group. I've fixed that.